# How do I test that a given mountpoint is mounted correctly?

Tags: linux, mount

Using any of `/etc/mtab`, `/proc/mounts`, `mount`, or `mountpoint` can give you incorrect information if any of the following have occurred:

- The remote is offline (`grep`-file based solutions fail)
- For NFS mounts, the remote has stopped exporting or the NFS service has been stopped (`mountpoint` fails)
- The remote has changed IP addresses (all solutions fail)

How can I retrieve a simple yes/no answer as to whether or not the mount is usable as intended?  As far as I understand, all of the mount information is stored in both `/etc/mtab` and in `/proc/mounts`.  Without causing a hang (as `stat` does), is there a way to verify that the actual state of the network is as the local information would lead me to believe?

This needs to be a very general tool, able to handle CIFS and NFS mounts (and others, most likely).

#### Constraint

I can only use what comes with the standard distribution on RHEL 6.  Usually, everything in `/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin` is fair game.  This is not by choice and is not a movable point, so I cannot accept an answer that uses external tools. For future readers' sake, though, I welcome them as comments `:)`

#### References

- [How to test if a given path is a mount point](//stackoverflow.com/q/479226/1443496)
- [What's the best way to check if a volume is mounted in a Bash script?](//serverfault.com/q/50585/167992)

Comment: Doesn't a plain `mount` show the IP address/hostname of the remote system for NFS mounts? (I know it does for CIFS)  `grep` it and then something like `ping` the host, which should fail faster than trying to access the remote mount.

Comment: @ultrasawblade For NFS mounts, I think so. But this may not apply to CIFS mounts, for instance. I'm not sure.

Comment: Related: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19535018#19535018

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid this is impossible.

The only way to find out if an NFS (or, more generally, any network) device is **usable** is to **try to use it** and that can block (and take quite some time).

Moreover, "un-usability" is not something permanent. If remote comes back up on-line, the mount becomes usable again.

Comment: I fear this might truly be the case, but I'll wait for more exposure before I consider the case closed -- I'm curious to see if others have come up with various hacks around the problem.  I see the logic in your point, but there are ways (e.g. for NFS, `rpcinfo` and `showmount`) to make *very* good guesses.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu I have created the mount points from `root`, but they are mounted to a different user, so checking the ownership gives me an indication of whether they were mounted or not.

All my mounts are in `/media` so the following script shows which have been mounted:

```
ls -ld /media/* |                      \
  while read x x usr grp x x x x name; \
  do if [ $usr == root ];              \
     then echo $name not mounted;      \
     else echo $name mounted;          \
     fi;                               \
  done
```

If you need to mount as root, perhaps you could use a different group and check that instead.

Note that this checks that a previous mount was successful. If a mounted device or network share subsequently goes down without being dismounted, accesses to it will still hang.